# Process TXT File according to its content

Tags: php

I have a txt file with the following structure:

```
1/1/0.00/191016/162249/1{
1/SAMPLE/0.00;
}
1/5/25.00/191029/092424/1{
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/BEER 500ML/5.00;
}
2/2/14.00/191029/092526/1{
05/WATER 550ML/7.00;
05/BEER/7.00;
}
#
```

As you can see the first line brings information about the sale and opens another "array" with each product that was sold. And then we repeat for two times.

I tryed to do something like:

```
   function readSalesFiles($file) {
        removeLastLineOfFile($file); //Function the sharp in the last line
        $strArray = file_get_contents($file);
        
        $collection = explode("\n",$strArray);
        $collection = array_filter($collection);

        if (count($collection)) {
            foreach ($collection as $linha => $collection_pipes) {
               echo json_encode($collection_pipes); //->> The problem is here
            }
        }
    }
```

Everytime i run this code my problem is to get element and understand if the element is the "parent sale" or the "child item sold" and turn them into the properly data I need.

The output that I have now is this:

```
1/1/0.00/191016/162249/1{ 1/SAMPLE/0.00; } 1/5/25.00/191029/092424/1{ 01/WATER 500ML/5.00; 01/WATER 500ML/5.00; 01/WATER 500ML/5.00; 01/WATER 500ML/5.00; 01/WATER 500ML/5.00; } 2/2/14.00/191029/092526/1{ 05/BEER 250/7.00; 05/BEER 250/7.00; }
```

What I need is to pick the text file and include de data in some database. To to that i would need to pick each sale like this:

```
{
   "insert_1":{
      "a":"1",
      "b":1,
      "c":"0.00",
      "d":"191016",
      "e":"162249",
      "f":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"SAMPLE",
         "j":"0.00;"
      }
   },
   "insert_2":{
      "a":"1",
      "b":5,
      "c":"25.00",
      "d":"191029",
      "e":"092424",
      "f":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"WATER 500ML",
         "j":"5.00;"
      },
      "g":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"WATER 500ML",
         "j":"5.00;"
      },
      "h":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"WATER 500ML",
         "j":"5.00;"
      },
      "i":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"WATER 500ML",
         "j":"5.00;"
      },
      "k":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"BEER",
         "j":"5.00;"
      }
   },
   "insert_3":{
      "a":"2",
      "b":1,
      "c":"0.00",
      "d":"191029",
      "e":"092526",
      "f":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"BEER 250",
         "j":"7.00;"
      },
      "g":{
         "g":1,
         "h":"BEER 250",
         "j":"7.00;"
      }
   }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: _“What I'm doing wrong?”_ - well for starters, you neglected to tell us what exact output you _want_ to get here.

Comment: If its possible, can you ask whoever creates this file to rewrite it as JSON for example. A much better way of communicatind data between apps

Comment: _“The output that I have now is this:”_ - according to your code, you are echo-ing JSON - but what you have shown looks _nothing_ like JSON.

Comment: Thanks guys. I put the output expected.

Comment: The machine that generates the file do not connect to internet so thats the only way we can work now, @RiggsFolly.

Comment: You dont need the internet to write data to a file in JSON format! OR XML or any sensible format designed for data transer between apps

Comment: Your `f` in the expected output now contains data for only one product - what about the second and third sale in your example input, which contain multiple products each? Do you want this `f` to become an array then, or do you want one full such line (including all the `a`, `b`, …) for each product?

Comment: What I should have said is the machine is too old. It was not designed for interactions and we don't have the source code to make changes. :(

Comment: Exactly  @CBroe tha was just a sample that i wirte by myself. I need to process the whole data

Comment: “Exactly’ _what_? I asked you an _or_ question, so which one of the two should it be? _“I need to process the whole data”_ - that does not answer what I asked you.

Comment: _“understand if the element is the "parent sale" or the "child item sold"”_ - well _obviously_ a new parent sale items begins, when the current line ends with `{`, and ends when the current line contains just `}` … and yet I do not see even an _attempt_ to check for that in your code.

Comment: @CBroe thanks. I has been a long night.  I updated the question with details of the JSON. About the “understand if the element is the "parent sale" or the "child item sold" thing: i tried differents approaches like check the last character of the line but nothing worked fine.

Comment: You can not have multiple items with key `f` on the same level, as your expected “JSON” currently shows.

Comment: Can you work with the data if instead of a nested object with those `insert_X` and `a`, `b`, `c`, … keys, it is just a numerically indexed array - like this, https://3v4l.org/3ceKr ?

Comment: Yeah! I Can @CBroe Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean, is it possible - the code that I used to transform your input data into that structure is right there in that example. (How long was that night you’re were having? :-) )

Comment: Right now i'm counting 32 hours without sleeping. I see the code Now, @CBroe. Real thanks, man

Comment: Okay, added that as an answer, with a few comments for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one approach to transform your input data into an *array* that has your desired structure - numeric keys, instead of an object with actual `insert_X` and `a`, `b`, `c`, … keys, but that should probably be sufficient for further processing.

```
$data = '1/1/0.00/191016/162249/1{
1/SAMPLE/0.00;
}
1/5/25.00/191029/092424/1{
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/WATER 500ML/5.00;
01/BEER 500ML/5.00;
}
2/2/14.00/191029/092526/1{
05/WATER 550ML/7.00;
05/BEER/7.00;
}
#';

$lines = explode("\n", $data);
$result = [];
$counter = -1;
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $values = explode('/', trim($line)); // trim to be safe, regarding whether line endings
                                       // read from the file are actually \n or \r\n
  $num = count($values);
  if($values[0] == '#') { continue; } // skip any lines that contain just #
  if($values[$num-1][strlen($values[$num-1])-1] == '{') { // { at the end means
                                                      // starting line of new sale item
    rtrim($values[$num-1],'{'); // cut that { off the last value
    $temp = $values; // add values into temporary array
  }
  elseif($values[0] == '}') { // } means ending line of sale item
    $result[] = $temp; // add temp array to result array
    
  }
  else {
    $temp[] = $values; // push values from product line into new sub-array of $temp
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Will yield the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0.00
            [3] => 191016
            [4] => 162249
            [5] => 1{
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => SAMPLE
                    [2] => 0.00;
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 25.00
            [3] => 191029
            [4] => 092424
            [5] => 1{
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01
                    [1] => WATER 500ML
                    [2] => 5.00;
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01
                    [1] => WATER 500ML
                    [2] => 5.00;
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01
                    [1] => WATER 500ML
                    [2] => 5.00;
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01
                    [1] => WATER 500ML
                    [2] => 5.00;
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 01
                    [1] => BEER 500ML
                    [2] => 5.00;
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 14.00
            [3] => 191029
            [4] => 092526
            [5] => 1{
            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 05
                    [1] => WATER 550ML
                    [2] => 7.00;
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 05
                    [1] => BEER
                    [2] => 7.00;
                )

        )

)
```

Getting an object with the actual `a`, `b`, `c`, … keys could also be achieved, f.e. by using `range('a', '…')` to create the necessary keys (ending character would have to be determined based on number of items, `chr(97)+x` or something), and then using `array_combine` to merge those keys and the values. Encoded as JSON in the end, that associative array would yield an object then. But if it is not really necessary, I did not want to add that level of complexity.